# Transitioning from UISearchDisplayController ==> UISearchController can't get search bar to show

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that was written for iOS 7 the I need to update as UISearchDisplayController is deprecated for UISearchController.

I have went through several tutorials and tried but I cannot get this to work, however I am close.

I am following this [pattern](https://github.com/Ja5onHoffman/UISearchController-Demo/tree/master/UISearchControllerDemo).

The problem I am running into is that the pattern I am following loads the data from a son file into an NSDict object, but my data is in an Array. No problem, I just modified the search to use a predicate (I hard coded something for now, get all records with an E in the name).

But I am getting the following error:

2017-09-12 13:01:41.538 Scoular[7644:1963822] -[employee isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000105580
2017-09-12 13:01:41.604 Scoular[7644:1963822] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[employee isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000105580'

In the SearchResultsTableViewController.m file, at the line

```
 cell.textLabel.text = self.searchResults[indexPath.row];
```

from the m file below. I am stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#import "SearchResultsTableViewController.h"

@interface SearchResultsTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *array;

@end

@implementation SearchResultsTableViewController

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [self.searchResults count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SearchResultCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.searchResults[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
@end
```

Header File

```
@import UIKit;

@class EmployeeDetailViewController;

#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "EmployeeDatabase.h"

@interface EmployeeListViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

Implementation File

```
#import "EmployeeListViewController.h"
#import "EmployeeDetailViewController.h"
#import "SearchResultsTableViewController.h"

@interface EmployeeListViewController ()  <UISearchResultsUpdating>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *employees;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResults;
@property (nonatomic,retain)  NSMutableDictionary *sections;
@end

@implementation EmployeeListViewController

BOOL isSearching;


//Do I still need this
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] ==
        UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    }
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Get array of employees and sections
    self.employees = [EmployeeDatabase getEmployees];



    self.sections = [EmployeeDatabase getSections:_employees];


    // There's no transition in our storyboard to our search results tableview or navigation controller
    // so we'll have to grab it using the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: method

    UINavigationController *searchResultsController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableSearchResultsNavController"];

    // Our instance of UISearchController will use searchResults
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];

    // The searchcontroller's searchResultsUpdater property will contain our tableView.
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;

    // The searchBar contained in XCode's storyboard is a leftover from UISearchDisplayController.
    // Don't use this. Instead, we'll create the searchBar programatically.
    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x,
                                                       self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y,
                                                       self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;


    // Set the back bar button
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Employees"
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                    target:nil
                                    action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;

}



#pragma mark - Table Sections
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSInteger tmpCount;
    if (isSearching) {
    tmpCount = 1;
    } else {
    tmpCount = [[self.sections allKeys] count];
    }
    return tmpCount;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.employees count];
}

#pragma mark - Table View


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    employee *thisEmployee =
    [[self.sections
      valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys]
                    sortedArrayUsingSelector:
                    @selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]
                   objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]
     objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     cell.textLabel.text = thisEmployee.fulNme;


    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString *tmpString;
    //if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        //tmpString = nil;
    //} else {
        tmpString =
        [[[self.sections allKeys]
          sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:
                                             )] objectAtIndex:section];
    //}
    return tmpString;
}

#pragma mark - Right side bar alphabetical index
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    NSArray *tmpTitle;
    if (isSearching) {
        tmpTitle = nil;
    } else {
        tmpTitle = [[self.sections allKeys]
                    sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    }
    return tmpTitle;
}


#pragma mark - UISearchControllerDelegate & UISearchResultsDelegate

// Called when the search bar becomes first responder
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{

    // Set searchString equal to what's typed into the searchbar
    NSString *searchString = self.searchController.searchBar.text;
    [self updateFilteredContentForAirlineName:searchString];

    // If searchResultsController
    if (self.searchController.searchResultsController) {

        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController;

        // Present SearchResultsTableViewController as the topViewController
        SearchResultsTableViewController *vc = (SearchResultsTableViewController *)navController.topViewController;

        // Update searchResults
        vc.searchResults = self.searchResults;

        // And reload the tableView with the new data
        [vc.tableView reloadData];
    }
}


// Update self.searchResults based on searchString, which is the argument in passed to this method
- (void)updateFilteredContentForAirlineName:(NSString *)employeeName
{

    if (employeeName == nil) {

        // If empty the search results are the same as the original data
        self.searchResults = [self.employees mutableCopy];

    } else {

        NSArray *searchResults2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fulNme contains 'E'"];
        searchResults2 = [self.employees filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        self.searchResults = [searchResults2 mutableCopy];

    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `updateFilteredContentForAirlineName` function you are searching from `self.employees` array which probably contains `employee` custom class object. For that reason your `self.searchResults` array also containing same class object.
But in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of `SearchResultsTableViewController` your are doing `cell.textLabel.text = self.searchResults[indexPath.row];` that means you are adding `employee` object as string in `cell.textLabel` which causing your app to crash. Instead you can try this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SearchResultCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    employee *thisEmployee = self.searchResults[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = thisEmployee.fulNme;

    return cell;
}
```